# TYPO3 returns "Array" to Fluid as String

Tags: arrays, typo3, fluid, viewhelper, typo3-7.x

I try to pass an array within my Viewhelper to the Fluidtemplate.
It always shows the string "Array". If I try to use it as parameter in the `f:for each` viewhelper, I get an exception because it is a string and not an array.
I used Typo3 6.2 before, now I have Typo3 7 and it stopped working.

```
public function render($uids) { // $uids='901,902,903'
    $uidArray = explode(',', $uids);

    $objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
    $repository = $objectManager->get('XXX\\X\\Domain\\Repository\\FooRepository');
    $query = $repository->createQuery();
    $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
    $query->matching(
        $query->in('uid', $uidArray)
    );
    return $query->execute()->toArray();
}
```

This is my Fluid template:

```
{namespace vh=My/Namespace/ViewHelpers}
<f:for each="{vh:GetArray(uids: '901,902,903')}">...</f:for>
```

Comment: what do you get if you pass your viewhelper to the debug viewhelper?

Comment: Something like that: 'Array' String(5)

Comment: That means your array is already casted to a string before being returned by the viewhelper.

Comment: exactly, and i dont understand why - thats my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot return an array with your viewhelper, because viewhelper always return strings.

You can however introduce a new variable to the current render context and then use this variable inside your viewhelper.

```php
public function render() {
  $returnArray = array('a' => 17, 'b' => 42);
  $this->templateVariableContainer->add('returnArray', $returnArray);
  $output = $this->renderChildren();
  $this->templateVariableContainer->remove('returnArray');
  return $output;
}
```

Inside your template you can then run a for loop over `{returnArray}`.

Comment: this works, thx! just dont understand why they changed it this way. It was possible to return an array directly to fluid

Answer (score 0):

Try a combination of `f:for` and `f:cycle` in your Fluid template. See the [f:cycle examples](http://flowframework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartV/FluidViewHelperReference.html#id8) in the Fluid ViewHelper Reference.

Comment: This would not work, because i cannot use a viewhelper which expects an array as parameter. The return value of my viewhelper is an string not an array.